# Arabic letter in initial, middle and final form

Tags: languages, arabic

I want to make a table with the Arabic alphabet. This table will contain English text as well as Arabic symbols. I'm using a code that looks like this:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\inputencoding{utf8}
\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic, english]{babel}

%and

\usepackage{arabtex}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This allow me to write lines like this:

```
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{ا} & elif
```

or to use arabtex like this

```
 \< k  > & kef
```

but if I want to write the middle form or the final form of an Arabic letter the first method does not work and I do not know if it is possible with arabtex. What else can I try?

Comment: I recommend that you use this character and the first method ـ

Comment: For example ـبـ

Comment: @Au101 that worked. I tried the same with characters drawn from the Apple special characters panel of my computer, and it did not work

Comment: Try using U+200D unicode character, called the "zero width joiner".  See here for more information: https://codepoints.net/U+200D

Comment: @Au101 Also it works for middle letters but for initial and final letters it adds an extra _ that I do not wish to have

Comment: @RobertAlessi can you be more clear on how to use it?

Comment: Yes sorry so you will want ب, بـ, ـبـ, ـب

Comment: replace ب with ت ث etc. etc. the ـ is the magic character, you just have to copy and paste it around your arabic letter. Unfortuantely right to left playing havoc with the formatting makes it kinda tricky to give you more help

Comment: It also definitely makes it difficult to produce, but you can copy and paste from wikipedia as i probably once did https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Table_of_basic_letters

Comment: This invisible character has been designed to make a letter "think" that it is preceded or followed by another letter which it should be attached to.  So for example, if you type the letter lām followed by U+200D, it takes the shape of a lām connected with what follows.

Comment: @Au101  I got that now, but in the PDF I'm still getting an extra bottom line for final and initial letters

Comment: @RobertAlessi should I copy-paste it? My computer displays the symbol as a box with a question mark

Comment: @Mauricio As this is an invisible character, copying it may be a tricky business. Don't you have access to an unicode keyboard? Also, I noticed that at least with `lualatex` some fonts display an extra, unwanted mark in place of what should be invisible. FreeSerif is fine though.  What is good is that this method gives you the exact shape of connected letters, without anything prolonging—and so twisting—them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the prefix and/or suffix, `ـ`, and join it with any character. Other than that, I suggest `polyglossia` and the following setup.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ا}   & alif \\
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{بـ}  & ba'a initial \\
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ـبـ} & ba'a middle \\
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ـب}  & ba'a final \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This worked but I will add that I had to use XeLaTeX and Al Bayan as font because my computer does not have Amiri

Comment: @Mauricio You can [download Amiri for free from its webpage](https://www.amirifont.org/). Libertinus and Libertinus Math (extensions, by the creator of Amiri, of Linux Libertine) are good companion fonts for other scripts.

Comment: You might also be able to install Amiri from your package manager, or it might be included with your TeX distribution. On Ubuntu Linux, you can `sudo apt install fonts-hosny-amiri`.